# using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ prove $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x+3}{1+\sqrt x}=2$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x+3}{1+\sqrt x}=2$$

i got

$$|f(x)-2|<|x-1||\sqrt x -1||\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt x)^2}|$$

$\to \delta=1,\epsilon=\sqrt 2-1$

Is that true ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just set the value of epsilon. You have to, for an arbitrary value of $\epsilon$, find such a value of $\delta$ that $|f(x)-2|<\epsilon$ for every $x$ for which $|x-1|<\delta$.

My advice:

Try to remove $x$ from the estimates of $|f(x) - 2|$. For example, you already have

$$|f(x)-2|<|x-1|\cdot C(x)$$

You already know that $|x-1|$ is smaller than $\delta$.

Comment: so i got $|f(x)-2|<\delta^2 |\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt x)^3}|$,my problem with $|\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt x)^3}|$

Comment: @user130806 How did you get $\delta^2$? The second element is $|\sqrt x - 1|$, how did you estimate it is smaller than $\delta$? For the third element, take a *hint*: it doesn't need to be smaller than $\delta$, it can also just be smaller than a constant.

Comment: by $$|f(x)-2|<|x-1||\sqrt x -1||\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt x)^2}|=|x-1||\sqrt x -1|\frac{|\sqrt x +1|}{|\sqrt x +1|}|\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt x)^2}|=|x-1|^2|\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt x)^3}|$$

Comment: sorry but i failed to got it

Comment: @user130806 *hint*:$(1+\sqrt x)^3 > 1$. What can you say about $\frac1c$ if you know that $c>1$?

Comment: i can say that $|f(x)-2|<\delta^2 =\epsilon$ ?

Comment: set delta=epsilon

Comment: (x-1)=(sqrt(x)+1)(sqrt(x)-1)

Comment: @user130806 Correct!